# How to Copy also selected item in Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, select, copy

I have a table with some field. You can add new lines. If you try to fill the fields and click "Copy" ( [HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/JKdfkUNY3cXzEoaN4Lf9?p=preview) ) you can see that the it adds one line, copy the text in the input, but not the selected item. Why? Can you help me?

```
  $scope.cloneItem = function(food) {
var itemToClone = angular.copy(food);
itemToClone.indice = $scope.rows.length;
$scope.rows.push(itemToClone);
```

}

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle example?

Comment: You can find it in my question http://plnkr.co/edit/JKdfkUNY3cXzEoaN4Lf9?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.cloneItem = function(food) {
  $scope.rows.push(food);
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/b2iwyDVzzCulhuw06bjl?p=preview)

Comment: It doesn't work, it copy and paste just the input text, not the selection! It always turn back on default

Comment: Unfortunately still does not work .... because when I change some field in a row copied , it changes also the values of all other lines